# Put Maven plugins in Artifactory repository

Tags: maven-3, artifactory, maven-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I would like to set up a Maven repository with Artifactory.

What are the steps to setup Maven plugins repo in Artifactory. I have to load Maven Jacoco plugin from Artifactory local repo.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your use case can be achieved with general instructions of [Maven Repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository) of Artifactory. Since, you would like to deploy maven type package/plugins, there would no difference in the setup.

We should be able resolve the deployed packages/plugins from maven clients without any issues. Is there anything difference in the use case?